# Como poner el campo fecha en un formulario, pero sin que salga el calendario "típico"

Tags: javascript, html, html5, css3, formularios

Estoy intentando hacer un formulario en el que tengo un campo para poner la fecha, como el siguiente:

```
 <p>
       <label for = "nacimiento">Fecha de nacimiento</label>
       <input type = "date" id = "fechaP" name = "nacimiento" >
 </p>
```

Pero claro, al pulsar sobre este campo, sale un calendario para elegir la fecha y me gustaría que el usuario pueda introducir la fecha a mano, es decir los número (ej. 06/07/2022). Y que al introducirlo, tenga un formato predeterminado, es decir dd/mm/aaa.
Estoy intentando buscar la forma, pero no se me ocurre nada.

Comment: Segun [su documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) el input tipo date por defecto muestra el formato de la fecha en el idioma del navegador (a mi me lo muestra dd/mm/aaaa por ejemplo) **pero** internamente siempre lo mandará con este otro formato: `aaaa-mm-dd`, el cual debes saber recoger en tu script de destino.  Pero ojo con lo que dice [aquí sobre el soporte entre distintos navegadores](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#manejando_el_soporte_de_los_navegadores).

Answer (score 1):

Prueba poniendo ***onClick="event.preventDefault()"*** , quedaria

```html
<label for = "nacimiento">Fecha de nacimiento</label>
<input type = "date" id = "fechaP" name = "nacimiento" onClick="event.preventDefault()" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" >
```

le agregue igual el placeholder para que no te pierdas

Comment: Parece una buena solución, no lo habia pensado, pero me da que [puede tener problemas según el navegador y el idioma](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#manejando_el_soporte_de_los_navegadores) que sea detectado por dicho input.  Quizás lo mejor en este caso sería que fuera del tipo `text` con un pattern y andando.

Comment: Hola, y con pattern como sería, he encontrado esto pero no me funciona.    <input type="text" pattern="\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}" class="datepicker" name="date" value="" />

Answer (score 0):

El usuario siempre puede escribir la fecha a mano al hacer clic sobre "dd", "mm", o "aaaa" respectivamente (mm/dd/yyyy en inglés). El calendario solo aparece cuando se hace clic sobre el ícono del calendario.

En caso que desees que no aparezca al hacer clic sobre el ícono, la respuesta de Fenix Senpai **onClick="event.preventDefault()"** es la solución (**no lo recomiendo** porque este es un comportamiento por defecto, y es posible que afecte al usar el formulario en un dispositivo móvil)